# How to debug AngularJS in Chrome Browser

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on AngularJS. I want to debug the code in the chrome.

In firefox i am able to debug it with the help of firebug.

Any Idea..? Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For Debug AngularJS in **chrome** you can use **AngularJS Batarang**.

Here is the Link for description and Demo:

[Introduction of Angular JS Batarang](http://angularjs.blogspot.de/2012/07/introducing-angularjs-batarang.html)

Download chrome plugin from here: [chrome plugin for debug AngularJS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en)

Answer (score 4):

What about Chrome Developer Tools?
In Chrome you don't need any extension..

See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/ for reference.

There also exists a special Extension for debugging AngularJS:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk