# Can AngularJs be debugged with Visual Studio Code (vs code) and Gulp webserver?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code

I am building an angular application and i am having trouble debugging it.

i am using Visual Studio Code and attempting to set up the launch.json file to allow debugging of AngularJs.

I am using Gulp-webserver to interact with the web application on localhost:9001

I am able to build the application with the task runner (task.json) in visual studio code but i cannot seem to get the debugger to work by attaching it.

How can i get the debugger to work so i can hit brake points using gulp-webserver?

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320746/how-to-debug-angularjs-in-chrome-browser.

Comment: You say you are running it on a webserver, which means the application itself is opened with a browser I guess (Chrome/IE/Firefox)?